# Simple Question - Shallow Copy (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, object, copy, deep-copy

OK, I always get confused about this.

Let's say I have this code.

```
Public Sub Bar(byRef pMap as clsMap)
Dim foo as new FooClass()
pMap.listOfFoo.Add(foo)
end Sub
```

This would mean that referencing 'Foo' or the item stored in 'listOfFoo' would reference the same object, right?  If I was to change a property of 'foo' - but not change it to a new object - both would still reference and would reflect the updated values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're storing a reference pointer to the `foo` object, so if you modify a property in one place, it will be visible in all other places where `foo` is referenced.

If you want to make a copy of your object, you should consider [object cloning](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/11/25/copying.html).